# Two dimensional array feeding

Tags: c#, arrays, feed

need to do an `arr[n,n]` which will do a result as `[0,0] = 0 [0,1] = 1 [0,2] = 3 [0,3] = 6 [1,1] = 0 [1,2] = 2 [1,3] = 5 [2,2] = 0 [2,3] = 3 [3,3] = 0`

Trying to feed that `arr` with two `for` cycles. Anyway, can't figure out how to set conditions to generate it as I want it.

Any hint is welcome.

I tried to feed an array with two `for` loops, where I tried to sum values. So many errors occur when I start typing code.

E: Need to solve last `if (else if (i > j && j == 0))`, problem is out of bounds. Any idea? Don't want to shuffle everything. Need to calculate [1-4,0] value.

> == [4,0] = 5, [3,0] = 9, [2,0] = 12, [1,0] = 14

```
Console.Write("Zadejte n: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()) ;
            int[,] array_prava = new int[n, n];
            int[,] array_leva = new int[n, n];
            int pulka = n / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // array_prava
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (i == j)
                    {
                        array_prava[i, j] = Math.Abs(j - i) + array_prava[i, j];
                        Console.WriteLine("[" + i + "," + j + "] " + array_prava[i, j]);
                    }
                    else if (j > i)
                    {
                        array_prava[i, j] = Math.Abs(j - i) + array_prava[i, j - 1] + i;

                        Console.WriteLine("11[" + i + "," + j + "] " + array_prava[i, j]);
                    }
                    else if (i > j && j == 0){
                        array_prava[i, j] = Math.Abs(j - i) + array_prava[i, j - 1] + i;
                        Console.WriteLine("22[" + i + "," + 0 + "] " + array_prava[i, 0]);
                    }

                }
                //   Console.Write("----------------------------\n");


            }
```

any hint is welcome

Comment: It looks like some of the code in your post got cut off. Can you consider re-posting the rest?

Comment: It's really not clear what the rules are on determining a value in the array.  Can you state the rules or give some complete examples?

Comment: @squareskittles added complete code

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // array_prava
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (i == j)
        {
            array_prava[i, j] = Math.Abs(j - i) + array_prava[i, j];
            Console.WriteLine("[" + i + "," + j + "] " + array_prava[i, j]);
        }
        else if (j > i)
        {
            array_prava[i, j] = Math.Abs(j - i) + array_prava[i, j - 1] + i;

            Console.WriteLine("11[" + i + "," + 0 + "] " + array_prava[i, 0]);
        }
    }
}
```